# Distributing k points among n entities to find distance between points?

Tags: c#, math

I have a known list of n entries. I also have a known quantity of k points.

I need to distribute those k points as equally distant to one another as I can among the n entries. The end result is that I know what distance (d) is between the points.

Example:

So if we had n={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} entries (n=6) and k=3, and we assume we can start from 0 always, then we'd end up with a result of 0, 2 and 4 getting a point each as the "distance" between them all is 1 (d=1).

I've been racking my brain on how to calculate the d for an hour now. I'm not sure how to do it.

- n will always be a list of integers.
- k will always be less than n and an integer
- d should always be an integer where k*d <= n.

I tried using the sqrt of n but that wouldn't work if I get fractions.

I know this sounds like a math assignment but it's not homework. It's just a problem I'm sitting with for a game.

How do I calculate d? I use C#.

---

Turns out what I actually needed was to discretely distribute k indices across n elements.

See an example of it in action here; https://youtu.be/SC0qwkNzvmo

You can see how bombs are distributed among players. That is what I needed but had difficulty explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you just need this:

```
int[] indices = new [] { 0, 2, 4, };

double distance =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, indices.Length)
        .SelectMany(
            i => Enumerable.Range(i + 1, indices.Length - i - 1),
            (i, j) => Math.Sqrt(indices[i] * indices[i] + indices[j] * indices[j]))
        .Average();
```

---

If you're trying to discretely distribute the `k` indices across the `n` elements, then this is it:

```
int n = 6;
int k = 3;

int[] bs =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, k)
        .Select(i => i * n / k)
        .ToArray();
```

That gives `0, 2, 4`.

Comment: I see distance is a double in your example. If it has to be an int, will this still work you think?

Comment: @OmniOwl- `Math.Sqrt` and then `Average` make it a `double`. How would you imagine it would work as an `int`?

Comment: Well imagine that the `indices` in your list is a list of IDs of players. Each "point" assigned to these indices will be an object that players chosen from the `indices` will start with. So let's say I have 25 players (n) and 4 bombs (k). I now want to assign 1 bomb k for every n player. But the trick is, I don't know how many indices to ignore between each player that has a bomb assigned to them. I need to calculate what players get a bomb attached and how many players there are between each assigned bomb so that they can be "equidistantly" spaced out among the players.

Comment: @OmniOwl - What does "'equidistantly' spaced out among the players" mean?

Comment: Go to this video; https://youtu.be/SC0qwkNzvmo pause once the bombs have been handed out to the players. If we assume Mario is 0 and the Goomba is 15 then we have 16 players. How did Nintendo calculate what players should get a bomb so that they are spread out fairly equally? (I know I said equidistant and that wasn't quite right, but hopefully the link illustrates better). I need to be able to calculate that because my number of players and bombs are both variable.

Comment: @OmniOwl - I've updated my answer. It's rather simple now. I think that's what you want.

Comment: I think this is better. Thank you! It's really hard to express what I need when it comes to math like this 